# I want to catch the multiple records of the comboBox in ExtJS when they are selected

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var allParameters;

    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbreviation', 'name'],
        data: [{
                name: 'ALABAMA',
                abbreviation: 'AL'
            }, {
                name: 'ALASKA',
                abbreviation: 'AK'
            }, {
                name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA',
                abbreviation: 'AS'
            }, {
                name: 'ARIZONA',
                abbreviation: 'AZ'
            }, {
                name: 'ARKANSAS',
                abbreviation: 'AR'
            }, {
                name: 'CALIFORNIA',
                abbreviation: 'CA'
            }, {
                name: 'COLORADO',
                abbreviation: 'CO'
            }, {
                name: 'CONNECTICUT',
                abbreviation: 'CT'
            }, {
                name: 'DELAWARE',
                abbreviation: 'DE'
            }, {
                name: 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA',
                abbreviation: 'DC'
            }, {
                name: 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA',
                abbreviation: 'FM'
            }, {
                name: 'FLORIDA',
                abbreviation: 'FL'
            }, {
                name: 'GEORGIA',
                abbreviation: 'GA'
            }, {
                name: 'GUAM',
                abbreviation: 'GU'
            }, {
                name: 'HAWAII',
                abbreviation: 'HI'
            }, {
                name: 'IDAHO',
                abbreviation: 'ID'
            }, {
                name: 'ILLINOIS',
                abbreviation: 'IL'
            }, {
                name: 'INDIANA',
                abbreviation: 'IN'
            }, {
                name: 'IOWA',
                abbreviation: 'IA'
            }, {
                name: 'KANSAS',
                abbreviation: 'KS'
            }, {
                name: 'KENTUCKY',
                abbreviation: 'KY'
            }, {
                name: 'LOUISIANA',
                abbreviation: 'LA'
            }, {
                name: 'MAINE',
                abbreviation: 'ME'
            }, {
                name: 'MARSHALL ISLANDS',
                abbreviation: 'MH'
            }, {
                name: 'MARYLAND',
                abbreviation: 'MD'
            }, {
                name: 'MASSACHUSETTS',
                abbreviation: 'MA'
            }, {
                name: 'MICHIGAN',
                abbreviation: 'MI'
            }, {
                name: 'MINNESOTA',
                abbreviation: 'MN'
            }, {
                name: 'MISSISSIPPI',
                abbreviation: 'MS'
            }, {
                name: 'MISSOURI',
                abbreviation: 'MO'
            }, {
                name: 'MONTANA',
                abbreviation: 'MT'
            }, {
                name: 'NEBRASKA',
                abbreviation: 'NE'
            }, {
                name: 'NEVADA',
                abbreviation: 'NV'
            }, {
                name: 'NEW HAMPSHIRE',
                abbreviation: 'NH'
            }, {
                name: 'NEW JERSEY',
                abbreviation: 'NJ'
            }, {
                name: 'NEW MEXICO',
                abbreviation: 'NM'
            }, {
                name: 'NEW YORK',
                abbreviation: 'NY'
            }, {
                name: 'NORTH CAROLINA',
                abbreviation: 'NC'
            }, {
                name: 'NORTH DAKOTA',
                abbreviation: 'ND'
            }, {
                name: 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS',
                abbreviation: 'MP'
            }, {
                name: 'OHIO',
                abbreviation: 'OH'
            }, {
                name: 'OKLAHOMA',
                abbreviation: 'OK'
            }, {
                name: 'OREGON',
                abbreviation: 'OR'
            }, {
                name: 'PALAU',
                abbreviation: 'PW'
            }, {
                name: 'PENNSYLVANIA',
                abbreviation: 'PA'
            }, {
                name: 'PUERTO RICO',
                abbreviation: 'PR'
            }, {
                name: 'RHODE ISLAND',
                abbreviation: 'RI'
            }, {
                name: 'SOUTH CAROLINA',
                abbreviation: 'SC'
            }, {
                name: 'SOUTH DAKOTA',
                abbreviation: 'SD'
            }, {
                name: 'TENNESSEE',
                abbreviation: 'TN'
            }, {
                name: 'TEXAS',
                abbreviation: 'TX'
            }, {
                name: 'UTAH',
                abbreviation: 'UT'
            }, {
                name: 'VERMONT',
                abbreviation: 'VT'
            }, {
                name: 'VIRGIN ISLANDS',
                abbreviation: 'VI'
            }, {
                name: 'VIRGINIA',
                abbreviation: 'VA'
            }, {
                name: 'WASHINGTON',
                abbreviation: 'WA'
            }, {
                name: 'WEST VIRGINIA',
                abbreviation: 'WV'
            }, {
                name: 'WISCONSIN',
                abbreviation: 'WI'
            }, {
                name: 'WYOMING',
                abbreviation: 'WY'
            }]
    });

    function myFunction()
    {
// add the variables here. 
    }
    var simple = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        title: 'Please select your certifications',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
        width: 350,
        layout: 'form',
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:100px;box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        shadow: 'true',


        items: [{

                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldlabel: 'Location',
                width: 120,
                emptyText: 'Select One',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbreviation',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbreviation} - {name}</div>',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),

                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '{abbreviation} - {name}',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),
                multiSelect: true,
                listeners: {
                    'select': 'myFunction()'
                }

            }],
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                formBind: true,
                handler: function(btn, evt) {
                    simple.getForm().submit({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/****/****',
                        params: {data: 'data'}
                    });

                }
            }]
    });

    simple.render(document.body);

});
```

Whenever a record is selected I want to add it to the variable
allParameters. Can someone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a lot of trial and error for this but the answer to this problem was actually very simple. ExtJS itself returns the values of all the records selected in a variable "list.value"

Refer to the following code:

```
 var simple = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        title: 'Please select your certifications',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
        width: 350,
        layout: 'form',
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:100px;box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        shadow: 'true',
        items: [{     
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldlabel: 'Location',
                width: 120,
                emptyText: 'Select One',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbreviation',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbreviation} - {name}</div>',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),                
                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '{abbreviation} - {name}',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),
                multiSelect: true,
                listeners: {
                    select: function(list) {                        
                        allParameters =  (list.value).toString();
                        alert(allParameters);                        
                    }
                }

            }],
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                formBind: true,
                handler: function(btn, evt) {
                    simple.getForm().submit({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/****/****',
                        params: {data: allParameters}
                    });

                }
            }]
    });
```

the variable allParameters in the above code stores the values of all the selected records